# criar dicionario com base em duas listas

Tags: python-3.x

tenho uma lista de items e outra de submenus (imaginem um cardápio), pois então, gostaria de criar um dicionario separando os itens pela chave de seu menu.
Não consegui desenvolver uma lógica que funcione para esse problema.
Segue código e um exemplo de rascunho de uma saída desejada.
obrigado.

```
items = [('a', 1),('b', 1),('c', 2)]
submenu = [('x', 1), ('y', 2)]
dictry = []

for i in range(len(items)):
    d = {}
    d['id_item'] = items[0][0]
    d['id_submenu'] = items[0][1]
    dictry.append(d)
    items.pop(0)

print(dictry)

#SaidaEsperada#
{
    "Menu": [
        {
            "X": [
                {
                    "id_item": "a",
                    "id_submenu": 1
                },
                {
                    "id_item": "b",
                    "id_submenu": 1
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "Y": [
                {
                    "id_item": "c",
                    "id_submenu": 2
                }

            ]
        }

    ]
}
```

Comment: Rodolfo, esta saída esperada que você colocou na pergunta não é válida, tente criar um dicionário válido, porque com essa estrutura não dá para entender como a saída realmente deveria ser.

Comment: @user140828 editei, mas basicamente preciso consolidar os itens com base no seu submenu correspondente. veja se vc entender agora por favor. obrigado

Answer (score 1):

Eu não entendi muito bem o que significa esses valores "X" e "Y", mas seria algo como isto o que você quer ?

```
import json

items_list = ["frango a passarinho","pizza de calabresa"]
id_item_list = ["ID_i234","ID_i566"]
id_submenu = ["ID_s1923","ID_s2341"]

items = zip(items_list,id_item_list,id_submenu)

dic = {"Menu":{}}

for item in items:
    dic["Menu"][item[0]] = {}
    dic["Menu"][item[0]]["id_item_list"] = item[1]
    dic["Menu"][item[0]]["id_submenu"] = item[2]

print(json.dumps(dic,indent=4))
```

Preciso entender melhor o que exatamente você deseja. Por exemplo, o que seria esse "id_submenu", se esse nome é fixo ou se é alguma variável, etc.

Comment: fantastico, vou tentar aplicar a sua orientação no meu problema, acho que da certo. Mas só para responder sua pergunta: na lista "submenu" eu tenho os submenus X com o id 1 e o submenu Y com o submenu 2.
na lista de itens, eu tenho os itens a, b, c seguindo com a "chave estrangeira" que "linka" o submenu.

Exemplo, o frango a passarinho esta para o submenu X:1 e a coca cola está para o submenu Y:2.

que ficaria assim

X:1 {
 frango a passarinho

Y:2 {
 coca cola

basicamente o que preciso é separar os itens de acordo com o código do submen..